# Need assistance with collision physics between two nodes

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I'm making a game where a ball rolls down a series of blocks and the player has to anticipate where the ball is going to end up. However, I have a problem with the collision physics that I can't seem to understand.

*The Problem*

Whenever the ball touches the paddle (What the player moves), the ball does not stop and keeps rolling until it rolls off the paddle. What I would like to happen is for the ball to stop as soon as it touches the paddle and "stick" there. The attributes for the ball are :

[image]

and the attributes for the paddle are :

[image]

Any advice or solutions would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you implementing a `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`?

If so, when you detect the collision you could set the ball's velocity to zero, like this:

`ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector.zero`

Comment: I agree with this answer, and would most likely take this approach, but if you want to create some effects, look into creating `SKFieldNode`s.  Something like a magnetic field will keep your ball in place

Comment: +1 for Knight's answer. Plus it would add authenticity to your game world, as balls don't usually stop for no reason.